# How to avoid \cellcolor overflowing when changing the space in the column?

Tags: tables, color

I reduced the space in the columns through the use of `@{}` in the column type:

```
\newcolumntype{M}{@{}c@{}}
```

The problem is that, when I combined this with the `\cellcolor` command, it overflows into the other columns. And if I remove the `@{}` space modification, then it sets it right.

So, how can I let the `\cellcolor` command now that I reduced the space of that column?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{@{}c@{}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l|M|c|M|M}
  & a & b & c & d\\
a & \cellcolor{black!50} 90.6 & 10 & 0 & 0\\
b & 0 & \cellcolor{black!50} 90.0 & 10 & 10\\
c & 0 & 0 & 95 & \cellcolor{black!50} 5\\
d & 0 & 10 & 5.5 & 8\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Overflowed cellcolor table]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fake the columncolor:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][0pt]}c@{}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l|M|c|M|M}
  & a & b & c & d\\
a & \cellcolor{black!50} 90.6 & 10 & 0 & 0\\
b & 0 & \cellcolor{black!50} 90.0 & 10 & 10\\
c & 0 & 0 & 95 & \cellcolor{black!50} 5\\
d & 0 & 10 & 5.5 & 8\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you'll get problems with viewing the vertical lines. With some zoom values they will not be visible. Printing is no problem.

Comment: The problem with the lines is really annoying, the main idea is to have a really nice looking document, both printed and digital. Is there any other option to achieve the same goal? Some other package to color the tables?

Comment: it is a problem with the viewer and not with TeX!

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that kind of problem.

In the code of your MWE, I have loaded `nicematrix`, replaced `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}` and used the key `color-inside` (alias: `colortbl-like`). That key specifies that there are instructions of color inside the main tabular.

The output is directly as expected (because, with `nicematrix`, the colored panels are drawn with PGF/Tikz and not with the mechanism of `colortbl`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{@{}c@{}}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l|M|c|M|M}[color-inside]
  & a & b & c & d\\
a & \cellcolor{black!50} 90.6 & 10 & 0 & 0\\
b & 0 & \cellcolor{black!50} 90.0 & 10 & 10\\
c & 0 & 0 & 95 & \cellcolor{black!50} 5\\
d & 0 & 10 & 5.5 & 8\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The vertical rules won't seem to disappear, whatever PDF viewer you use, whatever the level of zoom is.

[image: Output of the above code]